# Celery Task with AWS SQS Broker Cancels Immediately After Starting in Docker Environment

Tags: python, django, docker, celery, amazon-sqs

I'm experiencing an issue where a Celery task, configured with an AWS SQS broker, starts and then immediately cancels when run in a Docker environment. This behavior occurs despite the task executing successfully when run from PyCharm on the same machine. Below is the relevant part of the Celery configuration and the debug output I receive when the task is executed.

**Environment:**
Django version: 4.2
Celery version: 5.3.6
Broker: AWS SQS
Deployment: Docker

**Celery configuration:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery, shared_task
from firmwave import settings

app = Celery(
    'firmwave',
    broker=f'sqs://{settings.AWS_SQS_ACCESS_KEY}:{settings.AWS_SQS_SECRET_KEY}@',
)

app.conf.broker_transport_options = {
    'region': settings.AWS_SQS_REGION,
    'predefined_queues': {
        'celery': {
            'url': settings.AWS_QSQ_QUEUE_URL,
            'access_key_id': settings.AWS_SQS_ACCESS_KEY,
            'secret_access_key': settings.AWS_SQS_SECRET_KEY,
        },
    },
    'is_secure': True,
}

app.conf.enable_utc = True
app.conf.broker_connection_retry_on_startup = True
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Debug output:

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Event request-created.sqs.GetQueueAttributes: calling handler...
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Response body:
b'<?xml version="1.0"?><GetQueueAttributesResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">**<GetQueueAttributesResult><Attribute><Name>ApproximateNumberOfMessages</Name><Value>155</Value></Attribute></GetQueueAttributesResult>**<ResponseMetadata><RequestId>922533a1-ce80-5018-8f23-6d970e5039f6</RequestId></ResponseMetadata></GetQueueAttributesResponse>'
[2024-02-02 10:06:08,319: DEBUG/MainProcess] Event needs-retry.sqs.GetQueueAttributes: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0xffffb3475970>
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Sending http request...
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Certificate path...
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Response headers...
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Response body...
[DEBUG/MainProcess] No retry needed.
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Canceling task consumer...
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Closing consumer channel...
```

The Celery worker starts and appears to connect to AWS SQS successfully, but then cancels the task consumer and closes the channel without processing any tasks.

Ensuring that the AWS SQS queue exists and is accessible.
Verifying that the AWS credentials are correct and have the necessary permissions.
Running the same setup outside of Docker (where it works as expected).
I suspect the issue might be related to Docker network configuration or possibly some Celery settings that need to be adjusted for Docker environments, but I'm not sure what specifically needs to change.

Has anyone experienced similar issues with Celery and AWS SQS in a Docker environment, or can anyone provide insight into what might be causing this behavior and how to resolve it?